# How have attitudes toward "plagiarism" in literature changed since the Elizabethan era?

Tags: william-shakespeare, history-of-literature, christopher-marlowe

It's generally well-known that many of Shakespeare's dramas were "inspired" by, "plagiarised" from or otherwise "copies" of existing works. I use these terms advisedly because, of course, Shakespeare put his unique, insightful and lyrical spin on them to make them the plays that have resonated down the centuries.

Nevertheless, the fact remains that a lot of his plots were borrowed from other works. *Hamlet* came from the "ur-Hamlet", *Othello* from *El Capitano Moro*. According to Wikipedia, *The Merchant of Venice*, *Much Ado About Nothing*, *All's Well That Ends Well*, *Measure for Measure*, and *Romeo and Juliet* are all from Italian novelle.

It's noteworthy that many of these stories are actually themselves based on older stories, in some cases dating back to antiquity: *Romeo and Juliet* has similarities with a tale from  Ovid's Metamorphoses. Nor was Shakespeare alone in doing this: Marlowe based *Dido, Queen of Carthage* on parts of the *Aeneid*, and the result has many similarities to *Romeo and Juliet*.

In the modern era, such wholesale recycling of older and contemporary texts would likely be frowned upon and torn apart by critics. Yet in Shakespeare's day, it was seemingly common and accepted by audiences. My question is: what was the cultural attitude towards plagiarism in the Elizabethan era, why was it accepted and when and why did it change toward the more modern attitude?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about ‘serious’ literature and/or live theatre? Because if you're claiming that e.g. Hollywood _doesn't_ do remakes, reboots, rehashes, or otherwise recycle plots and stories time and time and time again, then you might have to explain that a bit…

Comment: @gidds Since this site is about literature, I would assume the question is implicitly scoped to literature and thus excludes film. (And the remakes you mention are subject to copyright agreements.)

Comment: Many books nowadays do only such changes from the best sellers as are required to evade copyright laws.

Comment: @Mary I'm entirely prepared to accept that the premise of my question is wrong: given that Shakespeare was the bestseller of his day, it may be that things haven't changed much at all. If you can build an answer around this argument, I'd certainly consider it.